# Role Based Access Control in a Tree System

Tags: database, database-design, rbac

I'm trying to figure out what the best way of creating a database for a user permission system that is structured as a tree system.

(for illustrative purposes) I have three levels of control: `1`Property Group, `2`Property, `3`Building. A property group has several properties, a property has several buildings.

I want to set up administration on each level.

a `PropGroupAdmin` can view and edit all the properties inside the set property group, and the buildings inside.

a `PropAdmin` can only view the set property and the buildings within

and a `BldngAdmin` can only view the set building

How I envision it working is that user Bobby is a PropGroupAdmin with a propertygroup id of 102. That would translate into a series of specific privileges that I could read from a view.

The question I have is how can I set up the GroupPrivileges table to be able to inherit (if that's the right word) the hierarchy? Essentially allowing me to create a view that I could just read to see if a user has the right permissions to perform a task.

I created a little chart of how I imagine it will work.
[image]

I know This won't work this way, I'm just trying to figure out hot to make changes to get a similar result.

Comment: alternatively, I'm thinking of keeping the database a bit simpler (still having roles, permissions, and role permissions) but generating the resulting model on the backend code side

Comment: could you please share what approach you took to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

why reinventing the wheel? Why don't you implement the Role Based Access Control standard? http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/SNS/rbac/

There are implementations for all databases.

http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/role-based-access-control.html

Comment: The standard RBAC doesn't solve the tree data structure problem (maybe the limitation is my understanding there)

Answer (score 1):

If this is not too late, have a look at this:

http://vita.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=guide_authorization

Comment: Google chrome blocks the link and flags it to be a dangerous site